# Distance/Time beetween two points in android google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-2

I want to create a simple app that determines the distance and the time to go to some location. The problem is I don't find really good documentation of google maps api v2 in android.

I already have a map and two location marked with a marker. I tried to draw the path between them but I get a straight line  and it's not logic for a user who will go to somewhere.

1) Is there any official documentation of google map Api V2?

2) Are there functions that determine location between two points and we can, for example, change the path by dragging (like in google maps site)? Or I must use external class programmed by users?

Comment: @IllegalArgument  already googled , but I don't know if use others class is correct or there is officiel methoded included in google api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you will need to look into this link for distance between 2 locations and time

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Basically, you will need to make http call to the google map service which returns JSON with everything you mentioned above,  sort your JSON into readable text to use in java

Comment: aw thanks When I read this solution before I thinked it's for google map api v3 (because of request HTML) thank you ! :) , So I will use external class  like this ?https://github.com/tato469/Android/tree/master/routes%20googleMaps%20v2

Comment: you welcome,  there are post in stackoverflow and on internet about how to sort JSON and draw path from the JSON,  look around .  Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much for answer I will search more this time before post :)

Comment: The link you mentioned above, its roughly the same about what you will found on the internet for drawing path.  But I will suggest you to take a look at really how it work first before applying the external class

Comment: okay I will understand , so for drawing the path it's necessery to use external class ? (and sorry for my lot of questions)

Comment: Assume the external class from that link is up to dated. what im worry about its that, some of the xml node from the class could be wrong if its not up to dated.  you could always give a try at that external class. For myself, I just research and put together the pieces I need from the net